# Facebook Share Value From PHP Session

Tags: php, facebook

Here is my situation, when a user is logged in they have an option to refer friends using their special referral code. I want to share this with Facebook, so I was using FB's sharer.php?u= option.

Here is what my link currently looks like, the users referral code is stored in the session.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com/fb/<? echo $_SESSION['referal']; ?>&t=Title%20Example" target="_blank"><span>Share on Facebook</span></a>
```

In my .htaccess file I have added this line for a cleaner url,

```
RewriteRule ^fb/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?fb=$1
```

I've already tested by going to mydomain.com/fb/REF_CODE_HERE and it works, the problem I'm having is that Facebook is not reading the open graph meta tags.

I've already added these Open Graph tags, yet Facebook is still reading what is inside my  tags

Is there a better way to approach this? It seems that Facebook is not reading my og: tags, and I am not sure why.